# Super Annoying SQL Server Temp .sql files Error -- Tried to keep naming them the same

Tags: file, ssms, temp

I feel like I may be the only person in the world experiencing this problem since I can't locate even anything on google with a solution this problem.

Whenever I open a new query window in SSMS, for some reason SQL Server tries to name the underlying temp .sql file like one of ten file names in my C:\Documents And Settings\Local Settings\Temp folder.  After a handful of new query windows, those file names all exist in my temp folder so it then it starts over and tries to name the new query window temp filename a name that already exists in the folder.  So every time I open a query window after a handful of windows are open I get a dialog telling me The file C:\Documents And Settings...\~vs67BC.sql (or ~vs66BC.sql, ~vs68BC.sql, etc) has been modified outside of the source editor, do you want to reload it or lose the changes made in the source editor?  Whatever I click doesn't matter, it just goes to the next one and if that file exists in my temp folder then it asks me again if I want to reload or lose changes.  Some times it takes like 8-10 dialogs before I get a new query window to open.

Closing out of SSMS doesn't fix the problem.  It clears the temp files but then when I reopen SSMS and open two or three query windows, it come back.

Anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this?